# How to find the mulitple file sizes using javascript

Tags: visualforce

```
<apex:page standardController="Case" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="False" id="pge">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{!URLFOR($Resource.web2caseResources,'web2case/css/validationEngine.jquery_Dacia.css')}" type="text/css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8" />
<!-- MaskValidation -->
<apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.MaskFuntion}"/> 
<!---ValidationPlugin---->
<script src="{!URLFOR($Resource.web2caseResources,'web2case/js/jquery_min.js')}" type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8"></script>
<script src="{!URLFOR($Resource.web2caseResources,'web2case/js/jquery.validationEngine-es.js')}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="{!URLFOR($Resource.web2caseResources,'web2case/js/jquery.validationEngine.js')}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="{!URLFOR($Resource.web2caseResources,'web2case/js/Rforce_ESWebtoCase.js')}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<style>
form{
   width:540px;
   background-color:#EDEDED;
   font-family: Arial,"Trebuchet ms",Verdana,sans-serif;
   font-size: 11px;
   font-family: Arial,"Trebuchet ms",Verdana,sans-serif;
   padding: 7px 7px 0px 7px;
}
div #button{
    float: right;
    margin-right: 3px;
}
input.text {
    border: 1px solid #DADCDE;
    color: #484848;
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 16px;
    padding-top: 4px;
}
p{
    font-family: Arial,"Trebuchet ms",Verdana,sans-serif;
    color: #A2A5A4; 
    font-size: o.70em; 
}
h2{
    line-height: 1.5px;
    font-family: Arial,"Trebuchet ms",Verdana,sans-serif;
}

#CPF_Web__c,#email,#Phone,#Fname1,#Lname1,#description,#VIN_Web__c,#License_Number_Web__c,#Address,#CEP,#Complemento,#Cidade,#Estado,#ContactMobile{
    width: 410px;
}
#Numero{
    width: 150px;
}
#Endereço{
    width: 410px;
}
#left {
   float: left;
}
#right {
    width: 50%;
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
}
div #backbutton{
    float: right;
}
</style>  
</head>  

<form id="formID"  > 
    <Label >Si quiere realizar una consulta, una reclamación o hacer una sugerencia, cumplimente por favor el formulario a continuación.Para poder gestionar su petición, necesitamos por favor algunos datos personales.
    </Label>
<br></br><hr color = "white"></hr>        
        <br></br>

     <label for="Title_Web__c"> Tratamiento</label><br/>
        <select  id="Title_Web__c">
            <option value="Mr.">Sr.</option>
            <option value="Mrs.">Sra.</option>
            <option value="Miss.">Sta.</option>
        </select><br/>
        <hr color="white"></hr>


<Label for="Lname" >APELLIDO 1*</Label>      
 <br></br> 
<input id="Lname" class="validate[required,length[2,20]] text-input " maxlength="20" size="20" type="text" style="width:500px" />
<br></br>

<span>       
<Label for="Fname" >NOMBRE*</Label>
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;
<Label for="Surname" >APELLIDO 2*</Label>
<br></br>
<input id="Fname" class="validate[required,length[2,20]] text-input" maxlength="30" size="20" type="text" style="width:250px" /> 
&nbsp;
<input id="Surname" class="validate[required,length[2,20]] text-input" maxlength="20" size="20" type="text" style="width:235px" />
</span>

  <hr color="white"></hr>

  <Label for="email" >E-mail*</Label><br></br>
   <input id="email" maxlength="80" size="48" class="validate[required,custom[email]]" style="width:500px" />

    <hr color = "white"></hr>

                    <Label for="phone" >Teléfono fijo</Label><br></br>
                    <input id="phone" maxlength="10" name="phone" size="48" style="width:500px" />
                    <hr color = "white"></hr>

                    <Label for="Mobile">Teléfono móvil*</Label><br></br>
                    <input id="ContactMobile" class="validate[required,custom[telephone]]" maxlength="10" size="48"   style="width:500px" />
                    <hr color = "white"></hr>
<span>       
<Label for="Dnumber" >Nº</Label>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;     
<Label for="Street" >Calle</Label>
<br></br>
<input id="number" maxlength="20" size="20" type="text" style="width:250px" />
&nbsp;
<input id="Street" maxlength="20" size="20" type="text" style="width:238px" />
</span>  

<br></br>
  <hr color="white"></hr>

<span>        
<Label for="flat" >Piso</Label>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
<Label for="door" >Puerta</Label>
<br></br>
<input id="flat" maxlength="20" size="20" type="text" style="width:250px" />
&nbsp;
<input id="door" maxlength="20" size="20" type="text" style="width:238px" />
</span>
<br></br>
  <hr color="white"></hr>

<span>        
<Label for="city" >Ciudad</Label>
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
<Label for="state" >Provincia</Label>
<br></br>
<input id="city" maxlength="20" size="20" type="text" />
&nbsp;
<input id="state" maxlength="20" size="20" type="text" />
</span>
<br></br>
  <hr color="white"></hr>
<span>       
<Label for="vin" >Chasis</Label>
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; 
<Label for="regno" >Matricula</Label>
<br></br>
<input id="vinno" maxlength="17" size="20" type="text" />
&nbsp;
<input id="RegNo" maxlength="20" size="20" type="text" />
</span>  

<br></br> 
  <hr color="white"></hr>

<Label for="km">Kilómetros</Label>
<br></br>
<input id="km" type="number" /> 
 <br></br>
   <hr color="white"></hr>
               <Label for="casetype">Tipo*</Label><br></br> 
               <select  id="Type" name="casetype" >
               <option value="Information Request">Solicitud de información</option>
               <option value="Complaint">Reclamación</option>
               <option value="Service Request">Sugerencia</option>
               <option value="Other">otro</option>
               </select><br/>
               <br></br>
   <hr color="white"></hr>
   <Label for="description">Descripción*</Label><br></br>
<Textarea  id="description" class="validate[required]"  maxlength = "800" rows="8" cols="57"/>    
 <br></br>
   <hr color="white"></hr>

     <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.jquery}"/>
     <script type="text/javascript"> 
         var __sfdcSessionId = '{!GETSESSIONID()}'; 
         var filesToUpload = [];   
         var uploadedFile = 0; 
     </script> 
     <style> 
       .FilebuttonStyle{       
           font-family:Arial,'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,sans-serif; 
           font-size:13px;color:#ffffff; 
           background-color: #169fcc !important; 
           text-decoration:none; 
           text-align:center; 
           border:1px solid #1691ba !important; 
           line-height: 25px;!important; 
           border-radius:4px; 
           display:inline-block; 
           cursor:pointer; 
           width:40px; 
       } 

     td.fileRow { 
           overflow: hidden; 
           font-family:Arial,'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,sans-serif; 
           font-size:13px;color:#ffffff; 
           background-color: #8db728; 
           text-decoration:none; 
           text-align:center; 
           border:1px solid #6c8049; 
           line-height: 32px;!important; 
           border-radius:4px; 
           //padding-left:10px; 
           //padding-right:10px; 
           background-image:linear-gradient(top,#9dcc3d,#7da223); 
           background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top,#9dcc3d,#7da223); 
           background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top,#9dcc3d,#7da223); 
           background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,#9dcc3d,#7da223); 
           background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(top,#9dcc3d,#7da223); 
           display:inline-block; 
           cursor:pointer; 
           width:120px; 
           overflow: hidden; 
 } 


 td.fileRow  input { 
     display: block !important; 
     width: 157px !important; 
     height: 57px !important; 
     opacity: 0 !important; 
     overflow: hidden !important; 
 } 
   .fileCheckBox { 
        width: 16px; 
     height: 16px; 
     display: inline-block; 
     margin: 3px 5px 3px 3px; 
     background-color: white; 
         //box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #b0b3ae; 
     text-align: center; 
     vertical-align: top;  
    } 

         .FilebuttonGroup{ 
          float:right; 
         padding-right: -70px!important; 
         } 
     </style>    
     <script src="/soap/ajax/32.0/connection.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 

     <script type="text/javascript"> 


     function uploadFile() 
         {                

         var cas = new sforce.SObject("Case");

         cas.Title_Web__c = document.getElementById("Title_Web__c").value; 
         cas.FirstName_Web__c = document.getElementById("Fname").value;  
         cas.Second_name_Web__c = document.getElementById("Surname").value;
         cas.LastName_Web__c = document.getElementById("Lname").value;
         cas.SuppliedEmail = document.getElementById("email").value;
         cas.SuppliedPhone = document.getElementById("phone").value; 
         cas.Cell_Phone_Web__c = document.getElementById("ContactMobile").value;
         cas.City_Web__c = document.getElementById("city").value;
         cas.State_Web__c = document.getElementById("state").value;
         cas.License_Number_Web__c = document.getElementById("RegNo").value;
         cas.VIN_Web__c = document.getElementById("vinno").value;
         cas.Type = document.getElementById("Type").value;
         cas.Subject = document.getElementById("Type").value;
         cas.description = document.getElementById("description").value;



         cas.Language_Web__c = "Spanish";     
         cas.CaseBrand__C = "Dacia";
         cas.Priority = "Normal";
         cas.Status = "New";
         cas.Origin = "DACIA SITE";
         cas.CaseSubSource__c = "Webform";
         cas.From__c = "Customer";
         cas.RecordTypeId = "012b0000000cQKC";
         cas.CountryCase__c = "Spain";

         var caseResult = sforce.connection.create([cas]);  
         var caseId = caseResult[0].id; 
         alert(caseId);


             $("input[type=file]").each(function(){ 

               filesToUpload.push($(this)[0].files[0]); 
             }); 

              for(var i = 0, f; f = filesToUpload[i]; i++) 
             { 
                 var reader = new FileReader(); 

                 // Keep a reference to the File in the FileReader so it can be accessed in callbacks 
                 reader.file = f; 


                 reader.onload = function(e) 
                 { 
                     var att = new sforce.SObject("Attachment"); 
                     att.Name = this.file.name; 
                     att.ContentType = this.file.type; 
                     att.ParentId = caseId; 


                     var binary = ""; 
                     var bytes = new Uint8Array(e.target.result); 
                     var length = bytes.byteLength; 


                     for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) 
                     { 
                         binary += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]); 
                     } 

                     att.Body = (new sforce.Base64Binary(binary)).toString(); 


                     var a = document.getElementById("fileID").files[0].size;

                     sforce.connection.create([att], 
                     { 
                         onSuccess : function(result, source) 
                         { 
                             if (result[0].getBoolean("success")) 
                             { 
                                 console.log("new attachment created with id " + result[0].id); 
                             }


                            else 
                             { 
                                 console.log("failed to create attachment " + result[0]); 
                             } 
                         }, 
                         onFailure : function(error, source) 
                         { 
                             console.log("an error has occurred " + error); 
                         } 
                     }); 
                 };   
                     reader.readAsArrayBuffer(f); 
             } 
         }                


       function addRow(tableID){                 

          var row = '<tr><td><input type="checkbox" onclick="processCheckbox()" name="chk" class="fileCheckBox"/</td><td class="fileRows"><input type="file" onchange="createuploadAttachment(this)" </td></tr>'; 
        $('#'+tableID).append(row);   

       } 

     function deleteRow(tableID) 
     {     
         try 
         { 
             var table=document.getElementById(tableID); 
             var rowCount=table.rows.length; 
             for(var i=0;i<rowCount;i++) 
             { 
                 var row=table.rows[i]; 
                 var chkbox=row.cells[0].childNodes[0]; 
                 if(null!=chkbox&&true==chkbox.checked) 
                 { 
                     table.deleteRow(i); 

                    filesToUpload.splice(i, 1); 
                    // console.log(filesToUpload); 
                    rowCount--; 
                    i--; 
                } 
             } 
            processCheckbox(); 
          } 
          catch(e) 
          { 
             alert(e); 
          } 
      } 

     function processCheckbox(){ 
            $("[id$='_remove']").hide(); 
          var checkCount=0; 
             $("#dataTable input[type='checkbox']").each(function(){ 
             if($(this).is(':checked')) 
             { 
                 checkCount++; 
             } 
            }); 
           if(checkCount >0){ 
                $("[id$='_remove']").show(); 
           } 

         } 
   </script> 
       <div class="FilebuttonGroup"> 
         <input type="button" value="-" id="_remove" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')"  class="FilebuttonStyle" title="Delete Row"/> 

         <input type="button" value="+" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" id="_add"   class="FilebuttonStyle" title="Add Row"/> 
        </div>    
         <table id="dataTable"  >       
             <tbody> 
                 <tr> 
                     <td> </td> 
                     <td class="fileRows"> <input type="file" id = "fileID" class="fileInput" onchange="createuploadAttachment(this);"/> </td> 
                     <td></td> 
                 </tr> 
             </tbody>        
        </table> 
    <input type="button" value="Enviar" onclick = "uploadFile()"/>
     <div id="statusid"></div>      
    <script> 
         $(document).ready(function(){ 
              $("[id$='_remove']").hide(); 
            $("[id$='attachmentBlock']").find('.pbSubsection').attr({'style':'margin-right:-70px !important;'}); 
          }); 

    </script> 

             </form>
  </apex:page>
```

I need to check the file size for how many files I add (should not be more than 25MB for each file). I am able to check 1 file size. My task is to check all the file size and if any one of the files size is more than 25MB , it should not be attached and should throw an error message in the page.

Please provide me the solution with the corrected syntax. Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Fyi this will not work in IE8/IE9 - http://caniuse.com/#feat=filereader.

Comment: @VenkatashKumarSakthivel welcome to SalesforceStackexchange. Please take a moment and read the help topic that details best practices for asking questions in this community. I would then suggest editing your question and narrowing down to a specific difficulty you are having. salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You can check the size while pushing the file instance to the array or when looping on the array. If there is an error then show alert on that element

```
for (var i = 0, f; f = filesToUpload[i]; i++) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    // Keep a reference to the File in the FileReader so it can be accessed in callbacks 
    reader.file = f;
    if (f.size < 25 * 1024 * 1024) {
        //error on  the file element.
        alert('File too large ' + f.name);
    } else {
        //proceed with upload
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks .. ITs working .. But if the file size is below or max 25 MB,the case is getting created. What I need to do is , if the file size is lesser than 25MB the case and attachment have to be created. If any of the file size is greater than 25MB , it should throw alert message and also the page has not to be submitted( I mean the case must not be created).

Comment: I guess then first you will have to check the sizes of each attachment. Set a variable  in your  java-script and if all file are below 25 MB set that variable as true. After that proceed with creating the case and uploading attachments if the variable value is true else show error if it is false.